# LINQ to List<> to String - Best Optimized Method

Tags: c#, linq, c#-3.0

I have a string `List<string>` this would apply to all Lists. I needed to get the first item in a string list and then convert what I got back to a string.

Here is the working code using linq:

```
public List<string> AppGroup = new List<string>();
var group = SearchParameters.AppGroup.Take(1);
string firstAppGroup = String.Join(",", group.ToArray());
```

My question would be; Is this the best method to do what I am going for? Is there a better or shorter way to write this out? A good example of considering performance would be appreciated. If what I have is fine and no changes are needed, please let me know.

I am using framework 3.5 and above.

Comment: you don't need the .ToArray() (in .NET 4.0 - not sure about 3.5), about the question, there's not a lot to discuss about, you asking what's the best way to join strings, I guess the framework method is a pretty good candidate ;)

Comment: Why are you calling `Join` on a single element(or empty) sequence? And the first line serves no purpose at all. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: @CodeInChaos AppGroup could be an enumarable of enumerables (the first line make no sense I aggree)

Comment: @Guillaume86 If it's anything but an enumerable of string, `string.Join` won't compile. But perhaps the OP wants the semantics of `First()`/`FirstOrDefault()` and not those of `Take(1)`

Comment: @CodeInChaos Ok I didn't read closely the question you're right (I always jump to the snippets ^^)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your current means of grabbing the first item in the list is somewhat long-winded, and stems from the fact that using `Take(1)` returns an `IEnumerable` rather than the item in question.

Assuming `SearchParameters.AppGroup` is `List<string>`

```
string firstAppGroup = 
  SearchParameters.AppGroup.FirstOrDefault(); //returns null on empty set
```

is a much briefer way of stating the same intent.

EDIT:

As @CodeInChaos states, if you don't want to deal with a null value, use the null-coalescing operator to substitute an empty string in the case that null is returned:

```
string firstAppGroup = 
  SearchParameters.AppGroup.FirstOrDefault() ?? string.Empty;
```

Comment: You should append a `?? ""` so it returns the empty string on an empty sequence, making it equivalent to the OP's code.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a one liner:

```
string firstAppGroup = String.Join(",", SearchParameters.AppGroup.First());
```

Comment: I don't think `SearchParameters.AppGroup` is a list of lists

Comment: That's not equivalent. But of course the OP's code sample doesn't make much sense. So this might very well be what he intended.

Comment: Yead looking at the name of the variables he perhaps just need var firstAppGroup = SearchParameters.AppGroup.First() ^^